# How to print GDI+ objects with correct dimensions?

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+

I need to develop an application to print labels previously created with an editor. Each labels has some graphic objects, like images, barcodes, texts,... and when I use the GDI+ drawing methods to print in a PrintDocument, the result is that the object dimensions are always smaller than what I expect. What unit of measure I should use for the objects? What is the best practice for printing objects with GDI?

Any help would be pleasant.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very detailed and lacks code example of what you have so far, but anyways. It seems like you have issues setting up your print graphics. You would have to define how to map your graphics to e.g. 300dpi print document.

If you would just google for your question about how to print something with GDI+ you'll find tons of examples and tips like this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2648/Printing-using-GDI-a-few-tips

:edit
if you have millimeter as unit, you can tell your graphics object to use it by defining

`gr.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;`

Comment: I have a list of objects with dimensions set in mm and I don't know how to convert them correctly in order to obtain the same dimensions on the printed page.

Answer (score -1):

crystal report would be your solution.